# Question's author claiming he can't upvote my answer because it will get him banned after already accepting another answer

Tags: support, voting

I'm not fully sure what this guy is going on about. The comments quoted below are from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15566376/1317805):

> I would like to up vote your answer but previously I was banned when voting up my question's answer after I accepted. Sorry!
>   ...
>   Yes! previously I have voted on more than one answer.
>   ...
>   Sorry! I don't give you up vote at this time.

Is there anything I can do here to claim my denied upvote? I feel like my candy has been taken away from me.

Comment: OP is obviously delusional. =/

Comment: That user seems rather confused. If they were banned, it was not because of upvotes. Being banned for upvotes was probably because of sock-puppetry (aka voting irregularities).

Comment: @Oded Judging by the edit history and comments, it is *highly* likely the language barrier is leading to such a large amount of confusion, yes. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fine to upvote and accept the same answer. This never results in any adverse action being taken against a user.

If a user *upvotes too many of another specific user's posts in a short time*, that is serial upvoting. It is automatically reversed by the system (the reputation conferred is taken away, that is--the actual votes on the posts are not changed), and someone who continues to do it will usually be suspended for a short time by a moderator. Perhaps that is what this person is thinking of.

Unless they have upvoted multiple answers by you today (which is possible), there's definitely no problem for them in upvoting the answer they've accepted. They're free to choose *not* to upvote it, but there's nothing wrong if they choose to do so.

If they've already upvoted a few of your answers today, then they are right to think they should not upvote any more of your answers today. Not even this one, which they have accepted.

It is possible to serially upvote without realizing that one is doing it. If you go to someone's profile, view multiple answers, and happen to upvote many of them because you think they're good, *that's still serial upvoting*, and it will be reversed, and a user may be suspended if they do this repeatedly. A moderator should warn a user before suspending them, however.

Please note that serial upvoting is *not* the same thing as sockpuppetry--you don't need multiple accounts to serially upvote someone. (Abusing multiple accounts to overcome system-imposed limitations such as those on voting, or otherwise to make a position appear more popular than it is or distort people's perceptions of how popular an idea is, is sockpuppetry.)